# Does app need to be re-uploaded to include push notification certificate?

Tags: ios, app-store, push-notification

I have an app that uses push notifications. These notifications work perfectly in development, but I have problems in production. When I signed and uploaded my app to the App Store, I didn't realize that I haven't habilitated the push notifications.

Do I have to add a new provisioning profile and re-upload the app just to fix this?

I'm using the same certificate and the same xx.p12.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by: "When I signed and uploaded my app to the App Store, I didn't realize that I haven't habilitated the push notifications."?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  After you complete the production push notification certificate setup you need to regenerate your provisioning profile and resign your app.

The reason for this is that the provisioning profile contains entitlements related to the push notification service and the all important aps-environment information.

If you do not recreate the provisioning profile these entitlements and information will not be included.

For more information you can view the [Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ProvisioningDevelopment/ProvisioningDevelopment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH104-SW1), specifically the provisioning section.